# Require once from outer directory

Tags: php, require

Im trying to design a web site. It's currently set up on wamp, and i use a script called "ComboboxForm.php" located in the following directory:

> wamp/php/proyecto/scripts

In ComboboxForm.php i need to  require a script that is located in

> "wamp/php/proyecto".

How can i require it from an inner directory? i tried

`require_once("../php/proyecto/conectar.php");`

but it does not work

Comment: Your current require is essentially looking in `proyecto/wamp/php/proyecto/`.  The `..` means 'one directory up from the current directory'.

Answer (score 2):

Just `require_once("../conectar.php");` should do. After all, it looks like the file to include is exactly one directory up relative to the script.